# how to remove duplicate letters when using css with html?

Tags: html, css

I am newbie with html css and here is my problem.

I coded a very simple html css program.

I want to put the text in the center and make it to be horizontally. But it was vertical, as you can see in this code

```
https:// codepen.io/anhbui2904/pen/ExoxoNN
```

In this code, I want it like this

GO TO NEXT APPROVAL
OK
TRY AGAIN

The text to be vertically lined up.

I know my question is very easy with you, but could you please spend a little bit time to fix it for me ? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - flexbox for the rescue.
Try to avoid `position: absolute` unless you want to have elements overlaying each other.

Also, I gave the `.wrapper` the width and height of the entire viewport, which may not be necessary in your case. It does need dimensions to center its child elements within.

if you want the text to be vertical just add `flex-direction: column` to the wrapper.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.btn {
 margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="btn">GO TO NEXT APPROVAL</div>
    <div class="btn">OK</div>
    <div class="btn">TRY AGAIN</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you, your answer is greate. But could you please help me a little bit more, if I want it like this 
GO TO NEXT APPROVAL 
OK 
TRY AGAIN
, i mean with with carriage return how can I do that ?

Comment: add `flex-direction: column` to the .wrapper css

Comment: I fixed it for you

Answer (score 1):

Wrap divs by `.container`. Then alinged that with `position: absolute` and `left` and `right`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="btn">GO TO NEXT APPROVAL</div>
    <div class="btn">OK</div>
    <div class="btn">TRY AGAIN</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://codepen.io/ebrahimi73/pen/WNdNJwm?editors=0100

Answer (score 0):

What your trying to do is `stack` vertically,
So

- Use `align-items: stretch;` and `flex-direction: column;`,
- with `display: flex;`,
- to the `.wrapper` class.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.btn {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="btn">GO TO NEXT APPROVAL</div>
    <div class="btn">OK</div>
    <div class="btn">TRY AGAIN</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```